# How can I get these functions to work inside my menu

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, user-interface, inheritance

I am trying to create a program to generate a grocery list, separate perishable and non perishable items, print out a subtotal for each subclass, a overall tax total and a overall total, as well as a on demand inventory. I have the code below, but I can't get it to work properly.... any and all help is greatly appreciated.  I am still new to this and am trying to learn. Please be gentle...

```
class Grocery_list():

    def __init__(self,name,price):
        """ Defines gorcery list item"""

        self.name = name.title()
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        """ Returns formated item info """
        return f"\nItem: {self.name}" f"\nPrice: ${self.price}"


    def get_name(self):
        """ Displays Item Name """
        return f"Item name: {self.name}"

    def get_price(self):
        """ Display Item Price """
        return f"\nYour item cost is {self.price}"

    def is_perishable(self):
        """ Defines if item is perishable """
        raise NotImplementedError ('Not Implemented in Grocery_list')

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.price = self.price + other.price
        subtotal = self.price
        return "Subtotal: " + '$%.2f' % (subtotal)




class Perishable(Grocery_list):
    """ Defines if item is perishable """
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        Grocery_list.__init__(self, name, price)

    def is_perishable(self):
        """ Defines if item is perishable """
        perishable = input(f"\nIs your item perishable, yes or no: ")
        perishable = perishable.lower()
        if perishable == 'yes':
            return True, f"{self.name} = perishable."
        elif perishable == 'no':
            return False, f"{self.name} = non-perishable."
        else:
            print ("\nI'm sorry, I didn't recognize your response. Please try again.")

class Non_perishable(Grocery_list):
    """ Defines if item is non-perishable """
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        Grocery_list.__init__(self, name, price)

    def is_perishable(self):
        """ Defines if item is non perishable """
        perishable = input(f"\nIs your item perishable, yes or no: ")
        perishable = perishable.lower()
        if perishable == 'yes':
            return True, f"{self.name} = perishable."
        elif perishable == 'no':
            return False, f"{self.name} = non-perishable."
        else:
            print ("\nI'm sorry, I didn't recognize your response. Please try again.")

#=============================================================================    ================================
# Everything below this line is the issue.  I can't get the functions to work I need on function for each
# Menu item. (Adding items, Removing items, cart inventory, and getting a subtotal, tax amount, and total bill)

perishable = []
non_perishable = []


# This will work for the non_perishable list, but not the perishable.     Don't know why
def create_grocery_item():
    """ Create an Item for the grocery list """
    name = input("\nItem Name: ")
    price = input("\nItem Price: ")
    perishable = input("Is this item perishable, yes or no? ")
    perishable = perishable.lower()
    if perishable == 'yes':
        name = name.title()
        item = Perishable(name,price)
        perishable.append(item)
    elif perishable == 'no':
        name = name.title()
        item = Non_perishable(name,price)
        non_perishable.append(item)
    else:
        print ("Answer not recognized. Please try again.")

# I can't get this to work at all.
def remove_grocery_item():
    name = input("What item would you like to remove?")
    name = name.title()
    if name in perishable:
        del perishable [name]
        print (f"\nItem {name} has been removed from your cart")
    elif name in non_perishable:
        del non_perishable [name]
        print (f"\nItem {name} has been removed from your cart")
    else:
        print (f"\nI'm sorry, but {name} isn't in your cart. Please try again.")


# This one seems to work fine.
def print_cart():
    """ Print Items in Cart """
    print (f"The perishable items are: ")
    for item in perishable:
        print (f"Item:{item.name}" + f"/Price:${item.price}")
    print (f"\nThe non-perishable items are: ")
    for item in non_perishable:
        print (f"Item:{item.name}" + f"/Price:${item.price}")

# Honestly, I am not even sure where to start here....I can't figure out if I should create a seperate function
# for this, or if I should make a method inside the parent class. I'm supposed to have it add up the subtotal
# for each category (perishable and non_perishable), print those out seperately followed by the tax for and the
# overall bill total.

def check_out():
    sum = 0
    for item in perishable:
        sum += item
        print (sum)
    for item in non_perishable:
        sum += item
        print (sum)


# Here is the code for the menu options. This seems to work fine. I just need to figure out the functions
# to plug in....

ans=True
while ans:
    print("""
    1. Add item to cart
    2. Remove item from cart
    3. Show all items in cart
    4. Check out
    5. Exit
    """)

    ans = input("Please select an option from the list: ")
    if ans == '1':
        create_grocery_item()
    elif ans == '2':
        remove_grocery_item()
    elif ans == '3':
        print ("\nHere is your current cart: ")
        print_cart()
    elif ans == '4':
        print ("\nYour total bill is: ")
        check_out()
    elif ans == '5':
        print ("\nThank you for shopping with us. Goodbye!")
        ans = None
    else:
        print ("\nI'm sorry, that isn't a valid selection. Please try again")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a `class Item`, with an attribute that tells if one `Item` is perishable or not, and a class `GroceryList` that is a collection of `item`, equipped with the appropriate methods:

Something like this, perhaps:

#### [Edit]:

I added a class for each `item` category, so each now has a distinct `type`; they both inherit from a base class that provides all the functionality. The base class could (but doesn't have to) inherit from `abc.ABC`; IDK if you are allowed to import modules, so I left it aside.
Outside of instantiation, the rest of the code remains unchanged, and so does the output.

```
class AbstractItem:   
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        """ Defines gorcery list item"""
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        """ Returns formated item info """
        return f"Item: {self.name}, Price: ${self.price}"


class PerishableItem(AbstractItem):
    @property
    def perishable(self):
        return True


class NonPerishableItem(AbstractItem):
    @property
    def perishable(self):
        return False


class GroceryList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def get_perishables(self):
        perishables = []
        for item in self.items:
            if item.perishable:
                perishables.append(item)
        return perishables

    def get_non_perishables(self):
        non_perishables = []
        for item in self.items:
            if not item.perishable:
                non_perishables.append(item)
        return non_perishables

    def __str__(self):
        res = ['Shopping List', '\n']
        res += ['\t', 'Perishables:\n']
        for item in self.get_perishables():
            res.append('\t\t' + str(item) + '\n')
        res += ['\t', 'Non Perishables:\n']
        for item in self.get_non_perishables():
            res.append('\t\t' + str(item) + '\n')
        return ''.join(res)


carrots = PerishableItem('Carrots', 12.5)
whiskey = NonPerishableItem('Whiskey', 45)
butter = PerishableItem('Butter', 22)

grocery = GroceryList()
grocery.add_item(carrots)
grocery.add_item(whiskey)
grocery.add_item(butter)

print(grocery)
```

#### output:

```
Shopping List
    Perishables:
        Item: Carrots, Price: $12.5
        Item: Butter, Price: $22
    Non Perishables:
        Item: Whiskey, Price: $45
```

Comment: While I like your approach, and it is absolutely much more elegant, I am required to have two sub classes (one each Perishable/Non_perishable).  I am beating my head against a wall to make this work and I don't seem to be able to get more than half of it to work at a time.....

Comment: haha, ok @itsFUBARsoSUAC , I slightly modified the code to satisfy the requirement for two `types` of `Item`.